# How to share image and caption from whatsapp on my android application

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, uri, whatsapp

So I'm sharing an image from whatsapp app to my android app. However, the caption which is attached to it is not part of the intent. Is there a way I can check if my caption is part of the intent?

I've already been able to achieve sharing of image. But the caption attached to it does not come with it. Also when I print the intent type, it shows as 'image/jpeg' and I believe that because of this, the caption is not getting shared in the intent in the first place.

```
ImageView SharedImage;
TextView SharedText;
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();
Log.d("Check Type", action + " " + type);
Uri receiveUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
if (receiveUri != null) {
    SharedImage.setImageURI(null);
    SharedImage.setImageURI(receiveUri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the caption through

```
intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```